# Peripheral Devices

Tags: pcb, device

I have read few sources that says

> "Peripheral is a device which is connected to host computer but not
>   part of it. A peripheral is generally defined as any auxiliary device such as a computer mouse, keyboard, hard drive" - Wiki.

I am confused if I connect my computer(also consider microcontroller or microprocessor) to an host computer(lets say controller or server) will my system become an peripheral device for that host system?

**Note**: I am not sure if this is right place to ask this question please consider **migrating it to other site before down** voting or closing. I am not familiar with tags on this site please update if I add any **wrong tag** to my question. Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on perspective; a microcontroller can be a peripheral to a larger system, or it can have peripherals of its own.  Both could even be true at once, since the question is more one of language than of technology or architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In essence, yes, your microcontroller device, or System-on-Chip device, if connected to a host computer, will be considered a peripheral device for that host system.

In practical terms and from a purely technical / pedantic viewpoint, pretty much any device that is not an integral part of the host computer, but is connected to it, is a peripheral. This includes even internal hard drives or optical drives, and of course external devices (*internal in the case of a laptop*) such as displays.

On a contrary note, peripheral devices are typically understood to be devices which provide some type of facility, additional feature, or service to the core computing host, be it input, output, sensing *et cetera*. A microcontroller board such as an Arduino, or a single-board computer like the Raspberry Pi do not necessarily provide any feature or service addition to the host computer: It is up to the user to create an application on said boards to provide a peripheral function.

Thus from a non-technical viewpoint, the microcontroller board is merely using the host computer as a power source until it is put to some practical use, hence need not be considered a peripheral device until then.

Comment: Just to get this clear: I'm building a 'laptop' with 3 microcontrollers, one _main_, calculating everything, one _keys_, reading the keyboard and acting as stdin for _main_, and one _graphics_, acting as stdout for _main_. In this setup, _keys_ and _graphics_ are peripherals of _main_?

Comment: @Camil That would be my view, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call a server connected to a PC a peripheral of that PC. For a PC a mouse or USB-hub could be called peripherals.

For a microcontroller peripherals are usually the functions surrounding the CPU, most often on-chip.

I would use the rule that peripherals only extend to the limits of the **system**, like a mouse is part of a PC as a computer system, while a server is not. (Otherwise thanks to the internet all computers in the world would be peripherals.) Same for a microcontroller: timers and A-to-D converters are part of the microcontroller as a **system**.

Comment: A Centronics printer is a peripheral, but once connected through Ethernet and eg. a JetDirect card it isn't

Comment: @jippie: Centronics, isn't that 1970s? :) I would say directly connected = part of the system, via network it isn't. I admit it becomes a bit vague when you connect a USB printer via a (couple of) USB hubs